# Data mapping on different tables

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a data mapping project with Symfony 3.
Here is the specifications :

"It is often necessary to populate a database from flat files (csv) : various integrated tools into database services provide an upload space but this access is rarely operable by web users services.
Thus you are asked to provide a flat file import space, to detect columns (if applicable), to choose table fields to be populated, to propose a preliminary deletion of the table or a completion, to verify data typing, and synchronize data mapping."

So far, the flat file import is done correctly, I recover well the content and I display it in a dynamic table.
[image]

The problem comes at the time of insertion in the database! During my various data mapping tests, various errors were returned to me:

- Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
- General error: 1364 Field 'xxxxxx' doesn't have a default value

  ```
  $choiceMapping = $session->get('choiceMapping');
  $tableChoice = $session->get('tableChoice');
  $selectChoiceFields = implode(",", $session->get('selectChoiceFields'));
  $choiceData = $session->get('choiceData');

  $config = new Configuration();

  $connectionParams = array(
      'dbname' => 'xxxxx',
      'user' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
  );

  $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

  $sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();

  $tableDetails = $sm->listTableColumns($session->get('tableChoice'));

  if(sizeof($selectChoiceFields[0]) === 0)
  {
      $addFlash = $this->addFlash('danger', 'Choose at least one field !');
      return $this->redirectToRoute('mapping');
  }

  $host = '127.0.0.1';
  $db = 'xxxx';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $charset = 'utf8';

  $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
  $opt = [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
      ];
  try
  {
      $cnx = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
      die('Connection failed :'. $e->getMessage());
  }

  if($choiceMapping === "completion")
  {
      $content = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$session->get('tableChoice').' ('.$selectChoiceFields.') VALUES ('.$choiceData.')');

      $content->execute();

      $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "Data saved successfully !");
  }
  else
  {
      $content = $cnx->prepare('Truncate '.$session->get('tableChoice'));
      $content->execute();

      $sql = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$session->get('tableChoice').' ('.$selectChoiceFields.') VALUES (:choiceData)');
      $sql->bindValue(':choiceData', $choiceData[0]);
      $sql->execute();

      $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "Data saved successfully !");
  }

  return $this->render('result.html.twig');
  ```

$choiceMapping which corresponds to insertion method (completion or truncate)

$tableChoice which corresponds to the chosen table on which you want to work

$selectChoiceFields which corresponds to the table columns on which we want to insert data : if I do a var_dump($selectChoiceFields), it will send me back : "name" because I want to work on the "name" column.

$choiceData which corresponds to the csv file data that we want to insert in the chosen column : if I do a var_dump($choiceData), it will send me back : "test","test2"